# Issue with multiple db in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql-server, ms-access, codeigniter-2

I have a project that is using mySql and access db. It is working right now but I have my access db info and query in my view which is a no no. I am trying to figure how to fix it to use it correctly in my model, view, and controller. Also how to get 2 db's working for codeiginter and be able to access the second one for my drop down list.

Here is the db config page

```
     <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 
        $active_group = 'default';
        $active_record = TRUE;
        $db['default']['hostname'] = '10.16.160.155';
        $db['default']['username'] = 'dcman';
        $db['default']['password'] = '123456';
        $db['default']['database'] = 'call_ins';
        $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
```

This is the view Page

```
                <?php $msg = $this->session->flashdata('msg'); if((isset($msg)) && (!empty($msg))) { ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success" >

                  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                <?php print_r($msg); ?>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php $msg = $this->session->flashdata('msg1'); if((isset($msg)) && (!empty($msg))) { ?>
                <div class="alert alert-error" >

                  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                <?php print_r($msg); ?>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        if (typeof console == "undefined") {
            console = {
                log : function () {}
            }
        }
    })();
</script>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Enter CallIns</title>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/javascripts/autofilltextbox.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/view.css">
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body id="main_body" >


    <div id="form_container">


<form class="" action="<?php echo base_url();?>callin/insert_callin" method="post">
<div class="form_description">
    <h2>Enter Data</h2>
</div>                      
            <ul >

<li id="li_1" >
        <label class="description" for="element_1">Date Scheduled</label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_1" name="Date_Scheduled" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d') . "\n";?>" required/> 
</div> 
</li>       
<li id="li_2" >
        <label class="description" for="Employee_Name">Employee_Name </label>
        <div>
<?php

try {

$dbName = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\fpdb\\staffing.mdb";
 $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};charset=UTF-8; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");

}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
$sql="SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMPLOYEE_NUMBER  FROM tbl_USERS WHERE STATUS='A' order by FIRSTNAME";

/* You can add order by clause to the sql statement if the names are to be displayed in alphabetical order */

echo "<select id='Employee_Name' name=Employee_Name value=''>Employee_Name</option>"; // list box select command


echo '<option value="none">Please select a user</option>';
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row){//Array or records stored in $row
echo "<option value=$row[FIRSTNAME],$row[LASTNAME]>$row[FIRSTNAME]  $row[LASTNAME]</option>"; 

/* Option values are added by looping through the array */ 
}
echo "</select>";// Closing of list box


?>
</div>
</li>   
<li id="li_3" >
        <label class="description" for="element_3">Employee Number </label>
        <div>
            <input id="Employee_Number" name="Employee_Number" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" required/> 
        </div> 
        </li>   


<li id="li_4" >
        <label class="description" for="element_4">Time Reported </label>
        <div>
            <input id="Time_Reported" name="Time_Reported" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo  date("m/d/Y")." ". date("h:i:sa");?> " required/> 
        </div> 
        </li>   

<li id="li_5" >
        <label class="description" for="element_5">Reason </label>
        <div>
        <select class="element select medium" id="Reason" name="Reason" required> 
            <option value="" selected="selected">Please Select..</option>
            <option value="Bereavement" >Bereavement</option>
            <option value="Clinic" >Clinic</option>
            <option value="FMLA" >FMLA</option>
            <option value="ILL" >ILL</option>
            <option value="ILL 2nd Day" >ILL 2nd Day</option>
            <option value="Jury Duty" >Jury Duty</option>
            <option value="ILL/PTO" >ILL/PTO</option>
            <option value="IOW" >IOW</option>
            <option value="Late" >Late</option>
            <option value="Late???" >Late??</option>
            <option value="Late FMLA" >Late FMLA</option>
            <option value="Layoff" >Layoff</option>
            <option value="Leave Early" >Leave Early</option>
            <option value="LeaveEarly FMLA" >Leave Early FMLA</option>
            <option value="LeaveEarly ILL" >Leave Early ILL</option>
            <option value="LeaveEarly Personal" >Leave Early Personal</option>
            <option value="LeaveEarly FMLA" >Leave Early FMLA</option>
            <option value="LNTB5H" >LNTB5H</option>
            <option value="MIA" >MIA</option>
            <option value="NCI" >NCI</option>
            <option value="NCIBOD" >NCIBOD</option>
            <option value="NCIFL" >NCIFL</option>
            <option value="NCOFL" >NCOFL</option>
            <option value="Personal" >Personal</option>
            <option value="SAC" >SAC</option>
            <option value="STO" >STO</option>
            <option value="VLO" >VLO</option>
        </select>
        </div> 
        </li>
<li id="6" >
        <label class="description" for="element_6">Scheduled Area </label>
        <div>
            <input id="Scheduled_Area" name="Scheduled_Area" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" required/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       
<li id="li_7" >
        <label class="description" for="Contact">Contact</label>
        <div>
            <?php

try {

$dbName = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\fpdb\\staffing.mdb";
 $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};charset=UTF-8; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");

}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
$sql="SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, SCHEDULEPRIORTY  FROM tbl_USERS WHERE (SCHEDULEPRIORTY = 1) OR (SCHEDULEPRIORTY = 2) OR (SCHEDULEPRIORTY = 3)  order by FIRSTNAME";

/* You can add order by clause to the sql statement if the names are to be displayed in alphabetical order */

echo "<select id='Contact' name=Contact value=''>Contact</option>"; // list box select command
echo '<option value="none">Please select a contact</option>';
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row){//Array or records stored in $row
echo "<option value=$row[FIRSTNAME],$row[LASTNAME]>$row[FIRSTNAME]  $row[LASTNAME]</option>"; 

/* Option values are added by looping through the array */ 
}
echo "</select>";// Closing of list box


?>

<li id="li_8" >
        <label class="description" for="element_8">Approval</label>
        <div>
            <input id="Approval" name="Approval" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" required/> 
        </div> 
        </li>
          <input id="Complete" class="default" type="hidden" name="Complete" value="NO" />
            <input id="Status" class="default" type="hidden" name="Status" value="1" />

        <li class="buttons">
            <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </li>
            </ul>
        </form> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Reworded for clarity.

Comment: Not sure what you mean and why are you connecting to the DB in the view and not through the Codeigniter DB Object?